# Работа расширения chrome в фоне

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

У меня есть расширения для Google Chrome, которое по таймеру выполняет действия на странице. Однако если хром свернут, то расширения не начнет выполнять требуемые действия в нужный момент, а только тогда когда я его открываю вручную. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы расширение работало в фоне.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "NIKE BOT V2",
    "description": "This extension will be for nike",
    "version": "14.88",
    "permissions": [
          "storage"
        ],
    "icons":{
        "48": "images/icon.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        { "matches": [ "https://gs.nike.com/?checkoutId*", "https://gs-payments.nike.com/*"],
        "js": ["checkout.js"], 
        "all_frames": true, 
        "run_at": "document_end" 
    }
],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

JS файл, который должен выполняться - 'checkout.js'

Comment: Никак. При неактивной вкладки все таймеры останавливаются.

Comment: Можете попробовать расширение Tampermonkey, не знаю точно сработает или нет, у меня вроде бы с закрытым окном работало.